# Create an SSH key for other account on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: ssh, ftp, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sdk

I have installed the Cloud SDK for Google Cloud. I've logged in using auth which redirected me to the gmail-login. Created the SSH key and even logged in by SFTP using Filezilla.

The problem is, when I log in using the gmail auth, SDK shell (or putty?) logs me into an account that is not admin. It has created another SSH user account (named 'Acer', after my pc) and logs me into it. Due to this, FTP starts at the `/home/Acer` folder. I want access to the `/home/admin/web` folder, but I don't have it now.

How can I create a SSH key for the admin account so that I can gain access to the folder mentioned above? Otherwise, is it possible to grant 'Acer' the permissions to access all the folders?

Comment: Can I ask, when you run the command `$ gcloud info` before you try to ssh into the machine, does it display the account/email address of the owner of the project?

Comment: Yes, it does. It shows my Gmail Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a few suggestions.

First a bit of background. If you run this command on your home workstation:

```
sudo find / -iname gcloud
```

You'll discover a gcloud configuration folder for each user on your home workstation. You'll probably see something like this:

```
/root/.config/gcloud
/home/Acer/.config/gcloud
```

If you change directory into `/home/Acer/.config/gcloud/configurations` you'll see a file named 'config_default'. This file will contain the default account to use for that user ('Acer').

Because you have performed `gcloud auth login` as that user, and during that process selected your gmail account, it will contain that gmail ID/account within the config file for that user. If you would like a user named 'admin' to log into your project, you could try adding a user named 'admin' to your home workstation, and then before attempting to use `gcloud auth login`, ensure you switch user on your home workstation to user 'admin'. This will generate a gcloud configuration on your home workstation for user admin, and propagate SSH keys etc.

If you want to create ssh keys manually there's some useful info [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-basics-how-to-install-ssh-keys-on-the-shell).

(For what it's worth, if you decide to use `gcloud compute ssh` to log into your instance home workstation, you can specify the user in the command you would like to log in as. For example `gcloud compute ssh admin@INSTANCE_NAME`).

> I want access to the /home/admin/web folder, but I don't have it now.

Even if you are logged into the machine as a different user (in this case 'Acer'), the folder `/home/admin/web` should still exist on the instance if it existed previously. If you land in folder `/home/Acer` have you tried changing directory to the folder above and then listing the folders to see if `/home/admin/` exists?

For example, from `/home/Acer` run:

```
$ cd ..
```

then

```
$ ls
```

You should be able to see `/home/admin/`.

> Otherwise, is it possible to grant 'Acer' the permissions to access
>   all the folders?

Yes this is also possible. If you access the instance as the project owner (the easiest way would be to log into the Console as the owner of the project and use the SSH functionality in the console to access the instance). Now you can run this command:

```
$ sudo chown Acer.Acer -R /home/admin/web
```

This will make user 'Acer' owner of directory `/home/admin/web` and all files/directories below it (thanks to the -R switch).

Now when you next access the instance as user 'Acer' you'll be able to access `/home/admin/web` by running the following and you'll also have read/write capabilities:

```
$ cd /home/admin/web
```

Comment: I used filezilla to see the files. There are three folders in `/home/` viz.- `Acer/`, `admin/` and the third one is my gmail name - `name_abc123/`.
 `Acer/` & `admin/` don't have a `.config/` folder. The third one has it. But there is no `configurations` folder in `name_abc123/.config/gcloud/` folder. 
This is my first time and this is getting overwhelmingly complicated. All I want to do is host a php website on the server. :/

Comment: Excellent glad to hear you can now access the folder, if the answer helped solved your issue please consider accepting it.